# Python - convert multiple series to dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas

is it possible to loop through a list of Series and convert them to dictionaries? If so, can i also name each dictionary?

```
import pandas as pd

r = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
s = pd.Series([5,6,7,8])
t = pd.Series([9,10,11,12])

series_list = [r,s,t]

#THIS PART OBVIOUSLY NOT CORRECT
for each in series_list: 
    each.to_dict()
```

Comment: `pd.Series` does have a [`to_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) method, so I don't understand why "THIS PART OBVIOUSLY NOT CORRECT"

Comment: looks legit to me

Comment: From the example you've given, the act of creating Series objects in the first place seems redundant to me. What is the context?

Comment: @DeepSpace because `.to_dict()` is not being assigned to anything.

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are trying to achieve here.  It is as simple as `dict_r = r.to_dict()`... but it's so simple I can't help but feel like you're asking for something else.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use pandas dataframe!

First let's name those series:

```
r.name = 'r'
s.name = 's'
t.name = 't'
```

Or in series contstruct as follows:

```
r = pd.Series([1,2,3,4],name='r')
s = pd.Series([5,6,7,8], name='s')
t = pd.Series([9,10,11,12], name='t')
series_list = [r,s,t]

df = pd.concat(series_list, axis=1)
```

Then use `to_dict`:

```
df.to_dict(orient='series')
```

Output:

```
{'r': 0    1
 1    2
 2    3
 3    4
 Name: r, dtype: int64, 's': 0    5
 1    6
 2    7
 3    8
 Name: s, dtype: int64, 't': 0     9
 1    10
 2    11
 3    12
 Name: t, dtype: int64}
```

Comment: `concat` is gross, though. Should they really be using `pandas` here at all?

Comment: @roganjosh "gross"?  What makes a method "gross" or not?

Comment: Actually, I see that you pass the list as first argument. I stand corrected. I had in my head that it still implicitly iterated the list items, sorry.